# I am using Excel and VBA in conjunction with Selenium to try and log into and grab date from a site

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am rather new to using VBA and Selenium and I am trying to use VBA to go to and log into https://ss3.shipstation.com/ in order to compile data from the site. I am having trouble targeting the username and password text boxes and having it login.

I have tried this on Internet Explorer and upon getting close to getting it to work I found out that ShipStation does not run well on Internet Explorer. That is the reason for using Selenium Chrome.

```
Option Explicit  
Private Chrome As New ChromeDriver

Sub ChromeAuto()

    Chrome.Start: Chrome.get "https://ss.shipstation.com/"

    Do While Chrome.Busy = True Or Chrome.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Chrome.Document.getElementById("UserName").Value = "UserName"
    Chrome.Document.getElementById("Password").Value = "Password"
    Chrome.Document.getElementById("btn-login").Value.Click

End Sub
```

I am expecting it to at least fill in the fields but it is returning:

> 'Runtime Error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

How do I correctly complete the fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a timed loop (or set a longer wait time - see bottom) to allow time for the element to become present on the page. I would also use SendKeys to fill out the values, and you cannot chain `.Value`, which is a property, along with `.Click`, which is a method.

Selenium Basic has its own syntax and implicit and explicit wait conditions. You have attempted to use syntax used with Internet Explorer automation and DOM Document traversal via MSHTML. That won't work here. Correct syntax is shown below.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, t As Date, ele As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://ss3.shipstation.com/"
    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .FindElementById("username")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ele.SendKeys "abc"
        .FindElementById("password").SendKeys "xyz"
        .FindElementById("btn-login").Click
        Stop '<==delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

I would suggest having a look at [this](https://codingislove.com/browser-automation-in-excel-selenium/) tutorial and the examples [here](https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic)

---

**Longer timeout:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver, ele As Object
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://ss3.shipstation.com/"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        Set ele = .FindElementById("username", timeout:=5000)
        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ele.SendKeys "abc"
        .FindElementById("password").SendKeys "xyz"
        .FindElementById("btn-login").Click
        Stop                                     '<==delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This is my first time really doing anything with VBA so it has been a tad confusing. I will look at those links you posted for more info.

Comment: No worries. Any further questions let me know. Am happy to help.

Comment: Back again for some more help. I am trying to select a date range picker, select today, and select apply. Looking at the code there aren't any ids or names that are selectable. What would you recommend for this?

Comment: Using css selectors possibly https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors . If you pastebin.com the relevant html I will have a look. .FindElementByCss("selectorGoesHere")

Comment: Here is a link to the pastebin https://pastebin.com/td8EUPdz. It includes the date range picker dropdown menu.

Comment: Looks like you can set input values e.g. .FindElementByCss("[name='daterangepicker_start']").SendKeys "yourDate"

Comment: Sorry to be a bother but if I want to have this date to be the current date every time what would be the best way to do this?

Comment: .FindElementByCss("[name='daterangepicker_start']").SendKeys  Date   (where Date is a function which returns today's date)

Comment: Thanks for the help but I was unable to get this to work. I have given up on this particular task for now and I am working on getting the <h2> value for Ready to Ship onto my spreadsheet. Here is a link to the pastebin for the code I am working with https://pastebin.com/UVTmQUPE.

Comment: From what I can see it is just the 3.

Comment: You could gather those with FindElementsByTag

Comment: Hello sorry for being a bother but I am still having issues actually grabbing the h2 tagged items and displaying them on my excel spread sheet. Here is a link to what I currently have https://pastebin.com/5CRZmgu2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can't tell from the code alone. I need the html. Might be worth posting a new question with the html inserted using the snippet tool and then dropping the link here. That way you can paste your code in as well and explain what isn't working and show the expected return values.

Comment: Here is a link to the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653504/how-to-grab-the-h2-text-from-div-using-vba-selenium-on-chrome-and-insert-dat