# How to grab the <h2> text from <div> using VBA Selenium on Chrome and Insert Date to SpreadSheet?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have been learning VBA for a project and I am having trouble grabbing certain elements out of the html and have them populate on an excel spreadsheet.

The code I have used has returned no errors and from what I can see it should be working.

Here is my VBA Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GrabShipping()

    Dim t As Date

    Dim ele As Object

    Dim driver As New ChromeDriver

    Dim post As WebElement

    Dim i As Integer

    Dim mysheet As Worksheet


    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    Const INURL = "https://ss3.shipstation.com/#/dashboard"
    Const URL = "https://ss3.shipstation.com/"

    Set mysheet = Sheets("Main")

    With driver
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
        t = Timer
        Do
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = .FindElementById("username")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While ele Is Nothing
        If ele Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        ele.SendKeys "Username"
        .FindElementById("password").SendKeys "Password"
        .FindElementById("btn-login").Click
     End With

     With driver
        .get INURL

        i = 2
        For Each post In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'row-fluid stats')]")
            mysheet.Cells(i, 1) = post.FindElementByXPath(".//*[following-sibling:[contains(text(),'New Orders'").Attribute("New Orders")
            mysheet.Cells(i, 2) = post.FindElementByXPath(".//*[following-sibling:[contains(text(),'Ready to Ship'").Attribute("Ready to Ship")
            mysheet.Cells(i, 3) = post.FindElementByXPath(".//*[following-sibling:[contains(text(),'Orders Shipped'").Attribute("Orders Shipped")
        Next post


        Stop               '<==delete me later
        .Quit


    End With


End Sub
```

Here is the HTML that I am trying to grab from:

```
<div class="header row-fluid"><div class="row-fluid stats">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>2,318</h2>
        New Orders
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>53</h2>
        Ready to Ship
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>2,265</h2>
        Orders Shipped
    </div>
</div></div>
```

I am expecting it to return the values in the s to my spreadsheet but currently when I run the code it results in nothing being added.

Comment: Hi @DaultonB, i don't know how to get text in the VBA but you can try this locator `//div[contains(@class,'row-fluid stats')]/div/h2` which will identify all the matches. Try and let me know at least it is printing first `h2` or not? Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the help. I added your code and it is not returning any data, not even the first h2.

Comment: Can you share your updated try here? How are you doing get text in VBA?

Comment: Here is the updated try: https://pastebin.com/TydirdPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a css selector combination

```
Dim item As Object, nodeList As Object, r As Long
Set nodeList = driver.findElementsByCss(".col-sm-4.col-md-4.col-lg-4 h2")
For each item in nodeList
    r = r + 1
    Activesheet.Cells(r,1) = item.text
Next
```

---

You can try re-using a timed loop

```
 Dim item As Object, nodeList As Object, r As Long
 t = Timer
 Do
     Set nodeList = driver.FindElementsByCss(".col-sm-4.col-md-4.col-lg-4 h2")
     If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
 Loop While nodeList.Count = 0
 If nodeList.Count > 0 Then
     For Each item In nodeList
         r = r + 1
         ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 1) = item.Text
     Next
 End If
```

---

I would recommend seeing if you can shorten the css selector, for example, to:

```
.col-sm-4 h2
```

Comment: This is also not working. It takes a few seconds for the page to load in before it can go to the  ss3.shipstation.com/#/dashboard could it be that it isn't loading in all the way before doing the search? Here is an update on my codeusing the css selector combination you posted: https://pastebin.com/6gH1YdXf

Comment: Glad it worked :-) You might try shortening the css selector to just .col-sm-4 h2  instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
post.FindElementByXPath(".//*[following-sibling:[contains(text(),'New Orders'").Attribute("New Orders")
```

Could you please try the below code and let me know if this help.

```
post.FindElementByXPath("//div[@class='row-fluid stats']/div/h2").Text
```

Comment: I added that code and it is still not inputting the data into my spreadsheet. Just want to confirm that the code is for sure in the right area for this before going forward. The code is in sheet1 (Main).

Comment: Can u please print the xpath value and let us know what is it is displaying null or any string

Comment: The xpath is //*[@id="dashboard"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/h2 and it is not displaying anything not a null or any string.

Comment: Print this value before you assign to cell. ```post.FindElementByXPath("(//div[@class='row-fluid stats']/div/h2)[1]").Text ``` OR ```post.FindElementByXPath("(//div[@class='row-fluid stats']/div/h2)[1]").innerHtml```

Comment: I added this value prior to mysheet.cells and it is still not returning any values. When it logs in it takes a few seconds before going to the page and then going to https://ss3.shipstation.com/#/dashboard could it be that it isn't loading in all the way before doing the search? Here is an update on my code: https://pastebin.com/T7bEr4HG

Answer (score 0):

You can identify `<h2>` node text using the below xpath :

```
//div[contains(@class,'row-fluid stats')]/div/h2
```

But you may get multiple matches as there are multiple `<h2>` tags for the provided class.

As you are looping, I assume that the loop will fetch the values one by one from the list so you can modify your

```
i = 2
For Each post In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'row-fluid stats')]")
    mysheet.Cells(i, 1) = post.FindElementByXPath(".//*[following-sibling:[contains(text(),'New Orders'").Attribute("New Orders")
    mysheet.Cells(i, 2) = post.FindElementByXPath(".//*[following-sibling:[contains(text(),'Ready to Ship'").Attribute("Ready to Ship")
    mysheet.Cells(i, 3) = post.FindElementByXPath(".//*[following-sibling:[contains(text(),'Orders Shipped'").Attribute("Orders Shipped")
Next post
```

like below :

```
i = 2
j = 1
For Each post In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//div[contains(@class,'row-fluid stats')]/div/h2")
    mysheet.Cells(i, j) = post.FindElementByTag("h2").Text
    j = j + 1
Next post
```

If the above code doesn't work the try the below code which will try to get that text using the class name and the tag name :

```
i = 2
j = 1
For Each post In driver.FindElementsByClass("row-fluid stats")
    mysheet.Cells(i, j) = post.FindElementByTag("h2").Text
    j = j + 1
Next post
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the help Ali. I tried both of those suggestions. They both didn't work but the second option returned 'Run-time Error 32'. As I mentioned to others who are helping me with this I wonder if the issue might be the webpage not being fully loaded in prior to trying to find the elements.

Comment: Try to give some delay before trying to find that element... Refer [This Link](https://codingislove.com/scrape-website-using-selenium-vba/) if you have any doubt on this. You can find the similar code here...