# Login with username and password to a website

Tags: excel, vba

i m not good in vba and i tried to create with chatgpt help but not work. I have:

1. A2=USERNAME
2. A3=PASSWORD
3. A4=LINK
4. A5=HTML

I dont want to open with internet explorer but with chrome or firefox or edge.

The vba i posted worked but make false when enter coz the link from login platform want to click first in a banner of the website to open and not with a direct link.

Is it possible the vba take from cell A5 the HTML of the banner and click for open the login platform?

This website has many different services with unique login platform for each one. Could u suggest me an idea of vba?

Thnaks a lot.

```
Sub OpenPlatformWithCredentials()
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim link As String
    
    ' Read values at cells Α2, Α3 και Α4
    username = Range("A2").Value
    password = Range("A3").Value
    link = Range("A4").Value
    
    ' Open default web browser with the link
    Shell "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe """ & link & """"
    
    ' Wait page loading '
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    
    ' Find username and password box '
    SendKeys username
    SendKeys "{TAB}"
    SendKeys password
    SendKeys "~"
End Sub
```

Comment: Internet Explorer is deprecated. Suggest you look into using [Selenium Basic]( https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+and+%22selenium+basic%22)

Comment: i download and run it buti sont know how to use :P

Comment: This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54598248/11318818) might help ... but there are others you can search for both on SO and elsewhere on the web